# Removing USB Devices and Sleep Mode Windows 7 Pro

Tags: windows-7, usb, sleep

The issue is that when I remove a USB device (I've tested hard drives and mice), the computer wakes up from sleep mode.

The only thing I've been able to find are links with this solution: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15132/stop-your-mouse-from-waking-up-your-windows-7-computer/

Unfortunately, when I attempt it, in the final step, there is no "Power Management" tab.  This also doesn't address the problem of removing other peripherals.

Help?  Thanks,
Ian

Comment: You want the computer to stay asleep as you pull off things that are connected to it? Or are you having sleep problems?

Comment: "computer to stay asleep as you pull off things that are connected to it"

Answer (score 0):

Check power management settings for all "hub"s listed under "Universal Serial Bus Controllers" in device manager.

.[image]

Comment: I had looked under USB Host Controllers, and didn't see the power management tab.  I DO see them for the hubs, though.  Unfortunately, they are already all set to allow-computer-to-turn-off-to-save-power, and the allow-wake is greyed out, but already deselected.  Thanks,